# Office 2013 Presenter View slides

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, presentations

In previous versions of office in presenter view, you could look at all the slides at the bottom and scroll right to the one you needed and jump to it immediately. There doesn't seem to be anything like this in office 2013. Is there any way to get this back?